# optimizing my.cnf for SELECT query MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

On a VPS (ssd) with 4GB RAM (Centos 7.2 with MariaDB) I have a large table that gets updated a few times a day without issues.

I'd like to optimize my.cnf so that SELECT queries on that table execute faster.

I have this so far in my.cnf:

```
max_allowed_packet=1024M 
query_cache_size=256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3072M
```

I had to set max_allowed_packet to a high value because I kept hitting the max value when importing feeds.

Caching is on and I set query_cache_size=256M and innodb_buffer_pool_size=3072M

It doesn't seem to make a big difference (just a little faster). One query was around 9 seconds, now takes 8 seconds.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is probably barking up the wrong tree. The problem is most likely to be wtih the index or lack of them.

Answer (score 1):

`max_allowed_packet=1024M` -- This takes away from other memory usages
`query_cache_size=256M` -- No; at this size is slows things down.  Not more than 50M
`innodb_buffer_pool_size=3072M` -- Since only 4GB of RAM, and 1G taken by first item, set this to only 1G

General rule:  "You cannot tune your way out of performance problems."  But you can *hurt* performance by arbitrarily raising tunables without understanding that they could lead to swapping.  And that swapping is *terrrrrible* for MySQL performance.

Performance issues need to look at the query and the table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`).  Sometimes it is as simple as adding a 'composite' index.  Sometimes a simple fix can speed up a query by more than ten-fold.

Tell us about the 'large table getting updated'.  Are you completely reloading it?  (If so, discussion #73);  Massive update: #49;  `SELECTs` hitting table at same time: #61.  Other?

(I made up those numbers, but it I feel sure that are answers somewhere in this forum.  If you can't find them; let's see your info; we can reinvent the wheel.)